# PHP - combine variables

Tags: php, variables

I'm coding a multilanguage page.

I have three variables:

- `$helper->namejob_de` (for German language; coming from Database)
- `$helper->namejob_en` (for English language; coming from Database)
  and
- `define("LANG", $TABS[$TABX]['lang']);`
  Defining the language in the `config.php` (contains 'de' or 'en')

Now, as you can see, the DB content has the ending _de or _en.

Is it possible to combine these two variables?

I've tried:

```
echo $$helper->namejob_.LANG
```

But, obviously this doesn't work. Are there other options for such a "merge" of two variables?

**EDIT:**
After reading all the comments I decided to refactor my database/code. It's really dirty so I will try aan alternative. Thanks anyway :)

Comment: Are you asking for [*variable variables*](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php)?

Comment: I have three variables, Is it possible to combine these two variables? Please which variables are you referring to?

Answer (score 3):

You could try this:

```
echo $helper->{"namejob_" . LANG};
```

It should work but it is not very clear.

Answer (score 1):

See a minimalistic example

```
<?php
class x
{
    function __construct()
    {
        $this->x_1 = 1;
        $this->x_2 = 3;
    }
}

$x = new x();
$y=1;
echo $x->{"x_".$y};
?>
```

You should make a class that handles this "dirty" work, pass a variable in the constructor for the language

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with the following syntax: `$var_{$language};` However, you might not want to do it like this. I suggest to either use an array or object to encapsulate this problem. If you have to combine strings, you will never be able to find out where it was set.

Comment: After reading all the comments I decided to refactor my database/code. It's really dirty so I will try an alternative. Thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

I think besides using two different variables to store two different languages, you may use two language files with same variable names. Include the language file that is currently active. This approach is used in oscommerce.

Comment: After reading all the comments I decided to refactor my database/code. It's really dirty so I will try aan alternative. Thanks anyway :)